# itemselector + ArrayStore. Set data dynamycally

Tags: extjs

All.

I found an [old post on Sencha forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262398-ComboBox-ArrayStore-dynamic-load-in-4-2-(working-example)), mentioning `store.loadData` as the way to set new info into an array store.

This seems to work for a combobox but not for an itemselector as you can see in this fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2hu9

What's the right way to do it for an itemselector?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `itemselector`, because the user that created `itemselector` did not anticipate that data can be brought into a store through other means than a pure `load`. Only a pure `load` fires the load event on the store, which itemselector listens to.

If you add the line `store.fireEvent('load', store, store.getRange());` to the handler to fire the `load` event manually after loadData, itemselector starts working. There may be better ways to do this, for instance having itemselector listen to `datachanged` event instead of `load` event, but this is a quick workaround.